# Google Cloud Messaging - Android Application

Tags: android, web, google-cloud-messaging

I have a Web page and I would like to send a message or alert to my Android application when some action happens in the web. Can I do it with GCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the FCM answer, you can implement your own interaction if you are not using Firebase as backend.
You need:

1. Register the device on the network (our app should interact with GCM platform and will receive an ID)
2. Register the device on your own backend (your app should interact with your backend and save the device id and the GCM id)
3. Implement from your backend the communication with the GCM platform (send messages to the device identified by its id using the GCM id)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it has been superseded by Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). See the Firebase [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.